# How to automatically fill in column values based on another difference column value

Tags: oracle

I have function takes two parameters and I want to make this function takes the parameters automatically from table B and add it to specific column in this table.

For example, if I have a function `getSomething(val_1 , val_2);` and it returns a value from table A. Table B is empty. Let's assume it contains three column (X , Y , Z)

```
   column X : contains val_1 values
   column Y : contains val_2 values
```

And I want:

```
  column Z : contains the value return from getSomething(col X val_1 ,col Y val_2);
```

And this function takes parameters from each row in column X and Y for values will be insert.

I will try to edit my question to be cleared why i want to do that

- For example if I have three tables (A , B , C) :
- Table A contains (col1 , col2 )user changed it dynamically that's mean may be delete all values and insert another values.
- Table B contains ID for all values will be in table A.
- This ID exist in table C with the another data we want to select it.
- The function created to fetch the ID from table B so we can fetch the data from table C.
- I know we can create a new table to insert the ID with data from table A by the select with function, then we can fetch the data, but I wonder if we can add this function directly into table A, so we will get the ID automatically without additional table.
- Finally, I want to say it's too hard to explain the system in the question because it's more complex , so i tried to make it simple.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

How can I do this?

Comment: Why these values need to be stored in a column? And not computed each time you need them, with a simple SELECT?

Comment: values in column X and Y changed by the time from anthore system, and calculated values by  this function is foreign key and it will used to fetch some data by difference calculation

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details (including table definitions, the FKs) and some sample data. The function code or a description of what it does would help, too.

Comment: well if i got you, you have two tables A and B. A has got two columns col1 and colb. B has got three columns X, Y and Z. You want to insert values of A.col1 and A.col2 into table B (X,Y)and the value returned by function into Z. I am right?

Comment: sorry no, B(X,Y) will be inserted by user, A contains (X,Y,O,...) and the function will fetch the value of O from table A depend on values inserted by user in B(X,Y) and put it into B(Z) automatically